# Escape data for csv rows

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x

I would like to implement [this](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/streaming/):

```
from flask import Response

@app.route('/large.csv')
def generate_large_csv():
    def generate():
        for row in iter_all_rows():
            yield ','.join(row) + '\n'
    return Response(generate(), mimetype='text/csv')
```

But that `join` is very fragile (does not escape anything). Is there a simple, accepted method of escaping data for csv rows?

I would like to avoid using a [full-fledged csv library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html): I do not want to write or read a csv, I just want a simple way to generate a single, escaped csv row.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to escape a csv is to use the csv module. You don't need to write to a file, just create a file-like object like this:

```
import csv

class DummyFile:
    def write(self, line):
        self.line = line

    def getvalue(self):
        return self.line

@app.route('/large.csv')
def generate_large_csv():
    dummy = DummyFile()
    writer = csv.writer(dummy)

    def generate():
        for row in iter_all_rows():
            writer.writerow(row)
            yield dummy.getvalue()

    return Response(generate(), mimetype='text/csv')
```